# How to change data on View in Spring Boot MVC?

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller

How can I change data on the view?
For example, I have page that renders the input, where i write the word, and after submiting(by button or link) i just get the translation of this word on the same page.
In my code i have service method `translate()`, that watches in database the word and gets the `translatedWord`. How can i render that translated word?

```
 @GetMapping("/translate")
    public String showTranslateForm() {
        return "word-translate";
    }

    @PostMapping("/translate")
    public String translateWord(@ModelAttribute("word") String wordToTranslate, Model model) {
        String translatedWord = wordService.translate(wordToTranslate);

        model.addAttribute("toTranslate", wordToTranslate);
        model.addAttribute("translated", translatedWord);
        return "redirect:/translate";
    }
```

And do I need @ModelAttribute("word")? because i use `model.addAttribute` things? I dont understand good difference between attribute in args and in body of method

Comment: What template engine do you use? JSP or Thymeleaf? Or something else?

Comment: @Troley Freemarker
It seems easier than others, but still so chaotic html becomes -_-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your back-end could look something like this (explanation below):

```
    @GetMapping("/translate")
    public String showTranslateForm(Model model) {
        if (model.getAttribute("toTranslate") != null) {
            model.addAttribute("wordToTranslate");
        }
        if (model.getAttribute("translated") != null) {
            model.addAttribute("translated");
        }
        return "word-translate";
    }

    @PostMapping("/translate")
    public String translateWord(@RequestParam("word") String wordToTranslate,
                                RedirectAttributes attrs) {
        String translatedWord = wordToTranslate.translate(wordToTranslate);

        attrs.addFlashAttribute("toTranslate", wordToTranslate);
        attrs.addFlashAttribute("translated", translatedWord);
        return "redirect:/translate";
    }
```

In your front-end (using Freemarker) you could do:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="/translate" method="post">
        <input name="word" type="text" />
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
    <p>
        <#if translated??>
            ${translated}
        </#if>
        <#if toTranslate??>
            ${toTranslate}
        </#if>
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

You will send a value (the `word` you are expecting in your controller method) by typing something into the input in the front-end and hitting the submit button.

The submit will trigger the method under `@PostMapping("/translate")`. The method will get the value from the input field (because of the input attribute `name=word`, which will be bound to `wordToTranslate` parameter in this function, because of the @RequestParam("word") annotation before it). We also inject `RedirectAttributes` into this function, so that we can add flash attributes, which will pass over the attributes to the `showTranslateForm` method.

When the attributes are passed over to `showTranslateForm`, the `model` will now contain the `toTranslate` and `translated` keys (which we added as flash attributes in `translateWord` method) and these can now be used in the Freemarker template. By the way, the `<#if translated??>` and `<#if toTranslate??>` if statements simply check whether those attributes exist (because they initially don't when we first enter this page, they do after the redirect).

I hope this information helps you to get on the right track!

Comment: Thanks so MUCH! it works, but still have question, why Intellij says about redirect:/translate "Cannot resolve controller URL '/translate'"?
and about "toTranslate" in second "if" scope in freemarker "Cannot resolve variable 'toTranslate'"

Comment: And why u use RedirectAttributes attrs, what the differnece with Model?

Comment: Great to hear! On the warnings, from my experience, IntelliJ sometimes inspects stuff in files like HTML, JS etc. and says that stuff doesn't exist or that it indeed cannot resolve variables, but that is not always true (as you can see in this case). The controller URL resolve warning is weird. You shouldn't get that. It's hard to say what it is caused by. The `RedirectAttributes` is actually of type `Model` and the difference is that RedirectAttributes can transfer data between redirects. Model just temporary holds attributes which can for example be used in views for render purposes.

Comment: Okey! Thanks much. What should I do to dont lose answer after refreshing page?

If i refresh, the answer of translating get lost. Do i need some knowledge about sessions or rememberme logic?
I guess i didnt get warns in redirect before(maybe cause of new update), additionally i got some red warns in entity classes if i dont provide genereted ID and my joincolumn, for example, is red warned too(asks to assign data source). I hadnt that before Intellij update

Comment: Sure, you're welcome. To not lose your answer you could for example save your translation into a database or you could temporarily hold it in the browser Local/SessionStorage with JavaScript. Hmm, about the errors in your entity class, that could be a lot of things, so that's probably something that you'd want to ask in another question and provide details about the errors in that question.

Comment: By the way, if the answer helped you, could you please mark it as accepted for potentially other people that get stuck on a similar problem? Thank you!

Comment: Of course i did) But i have less than 15 reputation, so its not recorded)

Comment: Ah right, forgot about that 15 reputation rule. Cheers!